# How do you solve $\cos(θ) = \sin(θ) = a$ non graphically?

Tags: trigonometry

If
$\cos(θ) = a$, and
$\sin(θ) = a$,
and if $a$ is between $-1$ and $1$, how could we find $θ$. I could do this graphically by finding the intersection of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ and $y=a$. But how could I find out with algebra, maybe the sign rules for each function in each quadrant.

Comment: $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, so, if $\cos\theta=\sin\theta=a$, then $2a^2=1$

Comment: Clearly $a\ne 0$. Then $1 = \dfrac {\sin \theta}{\cos\theta} = \tan \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)\iff\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)=\sin(\theta).$$

Hence

$$\frac\pi2-\theta=\theta+2k\pi$$ or $$\frac\pi2-\theta=\pi-\theta+2k\pi.$$

The second equation is impossible and finally

$$\theta=\frac\pi4+k\pi.$$

From this,

$$\sin(\theta)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}=a$$

which shows the condition for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin(t) = \cos(\pi/2-t)$,
if $0 \le t \le \pi$ then
$t = \pi/2-t$
or
$t = \pi/4$.

If $\pi \le t \le 2\pi$ then,
letting $t = \pi+s$
so $0 \le s \le \pi$,
since
$\sin(t) = \sin(\pi+s)
= -\sin(s)
$
and
$\cos(t)
=\cos(\pi+s)
=-\cos(s)
$,
we have,
again,
$\sin(s)=\cos(s)
$
so $s = \pi/4$
and
$t = 5\pi/4
$.

The value of $a$ is
$\pm \sqrt{2}/2$.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric solution:

In the first quadrant, $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are complementary angles.

So we have $\theta + \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, or $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi.$$

The other solution is in the third quadrant (where cosine and sine are both negative).

So the solutions are $$\theta \in \left\{ \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}\right\}+2k\pi.$$